# How to access user google drive from backend?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am connecting user on frontend which is in ReactJS and backend is in python.
Now when I connect the user, I get following data:

```
{
"aud": "some token",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"exp": "1544798733",
"expires_in": "3598",
"access_type": "online"
}
```

Now, when I am connecting through python,to upload a file to google drive, I need many more fields as the user credentials to successfully upload the file. How can I connect/upload file to drive? is there any other solution?

I am referring to [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) doc for drive access using python.

Answer (score 0):

In the doc provided by google drive, there are several steps that is related to the user credential in step 1. Did you choose them as what it provided in the doc?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) that will guide you to upload a file in the drive.

> You can send upload requests in any of the following ways:
>
> - Simple upload: `uploadType=media`. For quick transfer of a small file    (5 MB or less). To perform a simple upload, refer to
>     [Performing a    Simple Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload).
> - Multipart upload: `uploadType=multipart`. For quick transfer of a small    file (5 MB or less) and metadata describing the file, all in
>     a single    request. To perform a multipart upload, refer to
>     [Performing a    Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload).
> - Resumable upload: `uploadType=resumable`. For more reliable transfer,    especially important with large files. Resumable uploads
>     are a good    choice for most applications, since they also work for
>     small files at    the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload.
>     To perform a    resumable upload, refer to [Performing a Resumable
>     Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload).

If you are using python, here is a [sample code of basic upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#basic_uploads).

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

For the rest of details, you can refer to the docs.

Comment: Uploading is not the issue here. Issue is to authorize the user from backend to upload the file. User has been connected through frontend and now the file is to be uploaded from backend. Please read the question description.